# Generate sequence number in android

Tags: android

I want to generate sequence number that starts from 001,002 and continue like that.I want it to get incremented on each visit of that screen..Any help appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: AtomicInteger seq = new AtomicInteger();int nextVal = seq.incrementAndGet(); tried this but it is not getting incremented @vrundpurohit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this way

```
public void incrementNumber(){
 int count = 1;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            int defaultValue = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("count_key",count);
                 ++defaultValue;
                getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("count_key",defaultValue).commit();
}
```

Read like this

```
public int getNumber(){
int  count = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("count_key",count);
                System.out.println("The count value is " + count);
return count;
}
```

call these methods from the onCreate of the Activity

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.filters); 
            incrementNumber();
            getNumber();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to initialize your counter in `onCreate()` and increment it in `onResume()`, storing the counter in the class and not as a local variable.

Comment: can u post the link to the example or a sample code

Answer (score 0):

You can save page visited count in SharedPreference, So every time you visit that screen increment it by one. Ref link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref